# The generic type or namespace name 'T' could not be found in IEntity<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have an interface IEntity declared as

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
     T Id { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
    DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [Timestamp] byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    //int Status { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass it in an extension method like this

```
private static bool IsProxy(this IEntity<T> entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        var type = entity.GetType();
        return type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.BaseType != null 
        && type.BaseType.BaseType == typeof(IEntity<T>);
    }

 public static Type GetUnproxiedEntityType(this IEntity<T> entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

        Type type = null;
        //cachable entity (get the base entity type)
        if (entity is IEntityForCaching)
            type = ((IEntityForCaching)entity).GetType().BaseType;
        //EF proxy
        else if (entity.IsProxy())
            type = entity.GetType().BaseType;
        //not proxied entity
        else
            type = entity.GetType();

        if (type == null)
            throw new Exception("Original entity type cannot be loaded");

        return type;
    }
```

However, I am getting error message

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'T' is supposed to be a a generic data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the extension method a generic method.  Currently it's not, and so the compiler is wondering what T is.  EG

```
private static bool IsProxy<T>(this IEntity<T> entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    var type = entity.GetType();
    return type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.BaseType != null
    && type.BaseType.BaseType == typeof(IEntity<T>);
}
```